# Trouble extending an AEM component

Tags: components, aem

I'm trying to extend a component, but my new marquee.html updates aren't rendering on the page. The dialog updates are okay. Here's what I have:

Parent component

```
marquee
> _cq_dialog
> clientlibs
_cq_editConfig.xml
.content.xml
marquee.html
```

Child component

```
marquee2
> _cq_dialog (All these updates are working.)
.content.xml 
marquee.html (None of these updates are rendering.)
```

Shouldn't any changes in the child component's marquee.html file override the parent file? I've been researching to see if I missed a step and everything seems to be in order, but apparently I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

In the child component, the "marquee.html" file should be renamed to "marquee2.html" since the component node is named "marquee2".

Comment: Yes, in principle this is how Sling recognizes the "entry point script", so it first seeks for the name matching with selectors and extension respectively, then checks the same name, then does the method ("GET.html" for example). In this question's case, it seeks marquee2.html as one candidate, for example.